# Rotation in local coordinate system: angle edition gives strange results

Tags: interface, transforms

If I rotate an object in its local coordinate system, Blender behaves in a way which I do not understand.

Example. Let there be an object:
[image]
I rotate it with a mouse, by dragging the red ring:
[image]
Now I want to make a small correction by editing the text field `Rotate/Angle` in the dialog at the bottom left. As such edition previously gave unpredictable results, just to test it out, I select that text field and confirm with enter exactly the same value as was there before. I would expect the mesh to stay in place, but it is not the case:
[image]
Again, just to test, I press `Ctrl-Z` to undo and the mesh state goes back to the first picture, skipping the second step as if it never existed.

I do often such small corrections and it works, but not in this specific case of rotation in local coordinates. Why?

Comment: This is a known [bug](https://developer.blender.org/T85886).

Comment: I suspected that it is a bug, but Blender has so many switches that I also asked myself if I did not inadvertently toggle something which resulted in such a counter-intuitive behaviour.